# The maximal unramified extension is the intersection of the maximal unramified extension of a localization?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am reading Neukirch's book on Algebraic Number Theory, and there is a statement I can not figure out why it is true, and I hope someone here can help me. Apologies if question is at an inappropriate level.

Let $(K,v)$ be a non-archimedean valued field (not assumed to be complete) and let $L|K$ be a Galois extension of $K.$ Let $w$ be an extension of $v$ to $L.$ We do not assume $v$ to be discrete.

Define $G_w$ to be the decomposition group of $w,$ consisting of those $\sigma \in G(L|K)$ such that $w \circ \sigma = w.$  It is then easy to see that we have an isomorphism $G_w \cong G(L_w|K_v)$ where $K_v,L_w$ are the completions of $K$and $L$ at $v$ and $w$ respectively. In a similar manner, if $I_w$ denotes the inertia group of $w,$ then it is easy to see that $I_w \cong I(L_w|K_v),$ where the latter is the inertia group of the extension $L_w|K_v.$ We set $Z_w = L^{G_w}$ and $T_w = L^{I_w}.$ Then, by the above isomorphisms, we have that 
$$Z_w = K_v \cap L$$ and $$ T_w = L_w^{I(L_w|K_v)} \cap L.$$

The last piece of background needed is the following:
If $(K,v)$ is a non-archimedean valued field and $(L,w)$ is a finite extension (where $w$ extends $v$), Neukirch calls the extension unramified if the degree of the extension $L/K$ is equal to the degree of the extension of residue fields and the extension of residue fields is separable. If the extension is infinite, it is unramified if it is a union of finite unramified extensions.

Neukirch then aims to show, in Proposition 2.9.11 (pg. 173) that $T_w|Z_w$ is the maximal unramified subextension of $L|Z_w.$ He claims that we can reduce to the case when $K=Z_w$ is Henselian, essentially because we have the isomorphisms  $G_w \cong G(L_w|K_v)$ and $I_w \cong I(L_w|K_v).$ However, I do not see how such a reduction works. Why can we reduce to this situation? I assume the idea is to pass to the completion $K_v,$ but still the reduction is not clear to me.

Comment: Being unramified should not only mean (for finite extensions) the residue field degree equals the field degree, but also it should require that the residue field extension is separable.

Comment: You want to know why $Z_w$ is henselian. I'm not sure what Neukirch exactly needs here. For me, $Z_w$ is henselian iff it contains the henselization of $K$, but if $K = \Bbb Q$, then the henselization is $\overline{\Bbb Q} \cap \Bbb Q_p$ if I'm not mistaken, and this is not a number field (so in that case, $Z_w$ cannot be henselian, since we may take $L/\Bbb Q$ finite).

Comment: @Watson $Z_w$ is not in general Henselian, so this is not what I am asking. I am asking why one can assume that $Z_w$ is Henselian, presumably this is because one can pass to the completion $K_v = Z_w K_v.$